# Create View Helper in Zend Framework 2 to display News with a Service and Factory Class

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have just recently started with my first Zend Framework 2 Project and try to display the "Latest Adverts" on the Startpage of my Website. I came to the conclusion that I need a View Helper for this. I found an example for a View Helper, which I successfully implmented.
The Example is just an Array and will display randomly an element from the Array.

I had to create 3 files for this. In the folder View/Helper I created LatestAdvert.php and LatestAdvertFactory.php in the folder Service I created LatestAdvertService.php

Here the 3 files:

**1.The Factory for the View Helper:  Advert/View/Helper/LatestAdvertFactory.php**

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class LatestAdvertFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
  public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  {
    $locator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    $service = $locator->get('Advert\Service');
    $random  = $service->fetchSingleByRandom();
    $helper  = new LatestAdvert($random);

    return $helper;
  } 
}
```

**2.The View Helper Advert/View/Helper/LatestAdvert.php**

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class LatestAdvert extends AbstractHelper
{
  protected $random = null;

  public function __construct($random)
  {
     $this->setLatestAdvert($random);
  }

  public function setLatestAdvert($random) {
    $this->random = $random;
  }

  public function getLatestAdvert() {
    return $this->random;
  }

  public function __invoke()
  {
    $latestAdverts = $this->getLatestAdvert();
    return "<div>Latest $latestAdverts</div>";
  }
}
```

**3.The Service Advert/Service/LatestAdvert.php**

```
namespace Advert\Service;
use Advert\Entity\Advert as AdvertEntity;  //new
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; //new

class LatestAdvertService
{

  protected $pizzaList = array(
    1 => 'Salami', 
    2 => 'Tuna', 
    3 => 'Ham', 

  );

  public function fetchSingleByRandom()
  {

     // $random = array_rand($this->pizzaList); //old
     $random = $this->getServiceLocator()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')->findAdvertsByDate(); // new
     return $this->pizzaList[$random];
  }
}
```

**In the module.php I had to add the below entries:**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
                     'Advert\Service' => 'Advert\Service\LatestAdvertService',
                    ),
        'factories' => array(
                      'LatestAdvert' => 'Advert\Service\LatestAdvertFactory', //new
    );
}

public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(       
            'latestAdvert' => 'Advert\View\Helper\LatestAdvertFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

I am now trying to change the above to show my latest Adverts which come from the Database. I also use Doctrine 2, I have got an Advert Entity/Advert.php and Repository/AdvertRepository.php. I now thought that I need to create another Factory for the Service, which should sit in the Service Folder. So I created the following File:

**Service/LatestAdvertFactory.php**

```
namespace Advert\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class LatestSaleFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
  public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
  {
    $em = $serviceLocator->setEntityManager($serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM \EntityManager'));
    $service= new LatestAdvertService($em);
    return $service;
   }
 }
```

I then have to change the **public function fetchSingleByRandom()** in my Service to do something like this:

```
 $random = $this->getServiceLocator()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')->findAdvertsByDate();
```

But now I am totally lost in all this. Is my Service/LatestAdvertFactory.php actually correct? I would suppose that I need the EntityManager in the Service to use the Entity and Repository, so I thought to use a Factory would be good. I suppose I have to add that new Factory to the Module.php, but how can I now actually access my Repository Function in the Service? I am really lost and confused in all this. Does someone knows a tutorial which got a similar set up or could push me in the right direction? Thank you very much in advance.

I have now add my first changes to the above code and marked it with the word new, to show which direction I m going. If anyone got suggestions or sees that I walk in the wrong direction then it would be great if that would be pointed out. I am still a beginner and have not understand the Zend Framework fully, so I am sure I do many mistakes.

I have found a solution which seems to work. I am posting my new Service File here:

**3.The Service Advert/Service/LatestAdvert.php**

```
namespace Advert\Service;

use Advert\Entity\Advert as AdvertEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\Debug\Debug;


class LatestAdvertService implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{


/**
* Service manager.
* @var Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager
*/
private $serviceManager = null;

/**
* Sets service manager.
* @param Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $serviceManager Service manager.
*/
public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager)
{
    $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
}


/**
* Returns service manager.
* @return type
*/
public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->serviceManager;
}


public function fetchSingleByRandom()
{
    // Get Doctrine entity manager.
    $entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

    $random = $entityManager->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')->findAdvertsByDate();
    Debug::dump($random);

   // return $this->pizzaList[$random];
}
```

}

Even if the above is working, is this the correct way? What is my LatestAdvertFactory.php actually doing? I have the feeling I am going around the Factory now, but I really don't know, because I am lacking an understanding of the Zend Framework 2.

Comment: What is the difference between LatestAdvertService and LatestSaleService? Where are you going to call the repository's function for the data?

Comment: You have a lot of copy-pasted code that is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out and sorry, the LatestSaleService was wrong indeed, its supposed to be LatestAdvertService. I wanted to call the repository function in the public function fetchSingleByRandom() in my Service. You write that a lot of code is incorrect, do you mean the spelling or the code itself?